# angular js checkbox current state

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

Following is my code for checkbox and directive.

When user click on checkbox i wants to know the current state of checkbox. It is not working now

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fromExistingOffer" ng-model="formData.fromExistingOffer" toggle-existing-offer>


appModule.directive('toggleExistingOffer', function() {
      return function(scope, element) {
        element.bind('click', function() {
            alert(element.attr('checked')); // help needed here

        });
      };
    });
```

Comment: as far as you not creating isolated scope for your directive, shouldn't model be available via `scope.formData.fromExistingOffer` ?

Comment: why do you want that custom directive? Why don't you just use [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) instead?

Comment: What happens if you change attr to prop?

Comment: Your custom directive is registering a `click` event on the `checkbox` in order to check if the `checkbox` is checked or not. Why in the world would you want to create a directive like that? Why don't you just use either `ng-click` or `ng-change`. Then if you wan to know if the `checkbox` is checked just use the model: `formData.fromExistingOffer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have access to the scope in your directive, I would just use that.

```
element.bind('click', function(){
  alert(scope.formData.fromExistingOffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss a scope.$apply()... See also this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcolino/1re59ck8/)...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fromExistingOffer" ng-model="formData.fromExistingOffer" toggle-existing-offer>

appModule.directive('toggleExistingOffer', function() {
  return function(scope, element) {
    element.bind('click', function() {
      scope.$apply(function () { // help given here :-)
        alert(element.attr('checked'));
      });
    });
  };
});
```

*UPDATE*: sorry, fiddle was wrong, just updated it right now... :-)

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and worked awesome thanks "mrberggg"

```
appModule.directive('toggleExistingOffer', function() {
      return function(scope, element) {
        element.bind('change', function() {
            alert(scope.formData.fromExistingOffer);

        });
      };
    });
```